# Anchor tag is not working in IE7

Tags: html, css

Im facing a weird problem. The problem is that clicking the image nested inside the anchor tag doesn't take to its href link. This problem occurs onli in IE7.

My html code is below.

```
<div id="shop">
        <article>
            <figure class="visual">
                <a href="/de/index.php?section=shop&amp;catId=17">
                    <div class="categorie-image-wrapper">
                        <img border="0" src="http://shop.jci.ch/images/shop/butcher-lg.jpg.thumb">
                    </div>
                    <h3>Flyer, Medienmappe, Jahresbericht</h3>
                </a>
            </figure>
        </article>
    </div>
```

And My css styles:

```
article, figure {
            display: block;
        }
        #shop  a {
            border: 1px solid #0A85C8;
            cursor: pointer;
            display: block;
            float: left;
            margin: 0 17px 32px 0;
            width: 230px;
            text-decoration: none;
        }
        .categorie-image-wrapper {
            float: left;
            height: 150px;
            padding: 5%;
            text-align: center;
            width: 90%;
        }
        img {
            max-height: 80%;
            max-width: 80%;
            padding: 10%;
        }
        #shop a h3 {
            background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #0097D6;
            color: #FFFFFF;
            float: left;
            font-size: 16px;
            line-height: 20px;
            margin: 0;
            min-height: 60px;
            padding: 4px 5%;
            text-align: center;
            text-transform: capitalize;
            width: 90%;
        }
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you using any library to convert HTML5 elements to HTML4 elements? Otherwise you have invalid HTML. Although you have that anyway because you can't have a `div` inside an `a` tag.

Comment: yes.. html5shiv js for IE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using img you can set background of a div to your image

```
<a href="/de/index.php?section=shop&amp;catId=17">
   <div class="categorie-image-wrapper">
     <div style=background:url(http://shop.jci.ch/images/shop/butcher-lg.jpg.thumb);width:10px;height:10px;></div>
   </div>
</a>
```